# Checking if a Column exists in Database table

Tags: coldfusion

I am using the following code to check if a Column exists, when not then create it.

```
<cfquery name="qSelect" datasource="#dbname#">
    select Top 0 * from Elements
</cfquery>

<cfif not ListFindNoCase(qSelect.columnlist,"idLang")>
   <cfquery name="qAlterTable" datasource="#dbname#" dbtype="ODBC">
      ALTER TABLE Elements ADD idLang varchar(200) NULL
   </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Can someone suggest if there is better way to do this?

Comment: Not the way I would do it, but it looks like it will work.  I assume the sql is valid for the database engine you have.

Comment: What database software are you using?

Comment: If you are doing this as a one time job because it's the only way to access your db, just run the alter table query.  If the column is there, the error doesn't matter.  If this is part of some application, maybe you should step back and think about this.  It seems unwise to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would query the `information_schema` directly.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'idLang'
```

If you're checking multiple column names you can change the `=` to an `IN` and then perform the same check you're doing now (`listFindNoCASE`). I don't know that either way is faster/better, but this is how I would do it.

You don't specify a DBMS, but this will work for SQL Server and MySQL

Comment: The method in the question gets the same answer with less work.

Comment: *If you're checking multiple column names* Simpler to change the `=` to an `IN` clause. Then verify the query.recordCount equals the list length.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ColdFusion 8+, the best way is to use <cfdbinfo>.  Then you can use it with any database.

```
<cfdbinfo datasource="votethisway.com" name="myColumns" type="columns" table="tblPoll" pattern="idLang">
<cfdump var="#myColumns#" label="myColumns">
```

<cfdbinfo> returns a query object that contains all of the information about each column in the table.  The pattern attribute can be used as a filter to reduce the results to just the column that you are testing for.

Here's a <cffunction> that wraps it up in a nice package:

```
<cffunction access="public" name="tableColumnExists" output="no" returntype="boolean" description="returns true if a table column exists" verifyclient="no" securejson="false">
    <cfargument name="datasource" type="string" required="yes" hint="name of the datasource">
    <cfargument name="table" type="string" required="yes" hint="name of the table">
    <cfargument name="column" type="string" required="yes" hint="name of the column">

    <!---initialize private variables--->
    <cfset var local = StructNew()>

    <cftry>
        <cfdbinfo datasource="#arguments.datasource#" name="local.qryColumns" type="columns" table="#arguments.table#" pattern="#arguments.column#">
        <cfcatch type="Database">
            <cfreturn false>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

    <cfif local.qryColumns.RecordCount>
        <cfreturn true>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn false>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Both cfdbinfo and the querying the metadata tables directly will work. So "best" is relative ;-) However, `cfdbinfo` is more portable (if that is a factor).

Answer (score 1):

Matt's answer is best.

If you don't want to test first or you're using an awesome DB like JET, you could also just wrap the query in `<cftry>` tags

```
<cftry>
    <cfquery name="qAlterTable" datasource="#dbname#" dbtype="ODBC">
        ALTER TABLE 
            Elements 
        ADD idLang varchar(200) NULL
    </cfquery>
    <cfcatch type = "database">
        <cfoutput>#cfcatch.message# - #cfcatch.details#</cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</try>
```

Comment: I like this answer better than Matt's.

Answer (score 0):

So, i followed each suggestion in this dialog and each of them was another nut to tie. Then i spent another 3hrs on the internet and still didnt come up with a SIMPLE SOLUTION to this issue.

Knowing coldfusion to be a simple server-side language, i know there was some answer somewhere, so i tried the "columnList" function. Amazingly, this worked:

---

```
<cfquery name="my_Recordset" datasource="my_Datasource">
   SELECT * FROM my_Table
</cfquery>

<CFIF NOT ISDEFINED('my_Recordset.my_Column')>
   <!--- create column because it doesnt exist --->
<cfelse>
   <!--- drop or update column because it exist --->
</cfif>
```

---

Also, you may want to put all columns in the table in a List that you can search using the List Function, ListContains, as shown below:

---

```
<cfquery name="my_Recordset" datasource="my_Datasource">
   SELECT * FROM my_Table
</cfquery>

<cfset myList = #my_Recordset.columnList#>

<cfset mySearchResult = #ListContains(myList, "my_Column")#>

<CFIF mySearchResult is 0>
   <!--- create column because it doesnt exist --->
<cfelse>
   <!--- drop or update column because it exist --->
</cfif>
```

---

Comment: This is only a slight variation on a few of approaches mentioned already, and respectfully, this is not the best approach.  Most enterprise databases provide more efficient options for identifying existing columns via [information_schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) views. If for some reason your database does not support these views, or something similar, at the very least add a `where 1 = 0` clause. Otherwise, the query will return every record in the table, which is a waste of bandwidth since the data is never used.  Side note, none of the pound signs above are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old, but in case someone will looking for it.

This will return a boolean

```
QueryKeyExists(qSelect, "idLang")
```